# Phalcon4 Model Pagination

Tags: php, phalcon

I used to do my pagination below way in phalcon3.4 however, it looks like no clear way to do this in the phalcon4,

```
use Phalcon\Paginator\Adapter\Model;

$paginator = new Model(
    [
        "data"  => Robots::find(),
        "limit" => 25,
        "page"  => $currentPage,
    ]
);

$paginate = $paginator->getPaginate();
```

Answer (score 0):

It has changed a little in Phalcon 4.*

The best solution I have come up with is to use [QueryBuilder](https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/db-phql#query-builder)

```php
$numberPage = $this->request->getQuery('page', 'int', 1);
$criteria   = Criteria::fromInput($this->di, Robots::class, $_GET);
$parameters = $criteria->getParams();

$builder    = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()->from(Robots::class);

$paginator = new QueryBuilder(
    [
        'builder'    => $builder,
        'parameters' => $parameters,
        'limit'      => 10,
        'page'       => $numberPage,
    ]
);
$paginate  = $paginator->paginate();
//Optional check $paginate->getTotalItems() and flash if nothing was found.

$this->view->page = $paginate;
```